# How to create an object of a subtype based on an object of a supertype?

Tags: typescript

I have an object `compactUser` of a supertype and I want to create an object `detailedUser` of a subtype based on object `compactUser`, in a type safe manner.

I have a solution which works, `detailedUser1` in the code below, but I'd like something more flexible (along the lines of `detailedUser2`) for more complicated scenarios.

(Sorry, this looks like a basic typescript question, I did search for a solution, but ended up asking here.)

([code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHRYCqAztMgN4BQyVywAJgFzIgCumARtOQL7nmiSxEKACIQwcYABsItIiQrUaDJqw5RK1EHEwRGhMFFABzDVWIAPPQePdeCdCH3J7OPHKiMMrhAWJRkALxkdIwAjDzk9o5gyLRiEtKyfqGMouJSMu6BZKbIAHQFLrg+7gA0uVo6jADkLDrV5YoWNZgNtuQA9B3IAJKxDtUxksAA1ihgABbAhADcNGDVhMiY6FAoMNLmwGzSpchszDHQUKvI2CcgEJEOTnHpie4ATNlFbn7IcEtpCZl+vF3IZjYQh7PrEGIAAwsEL2BxiMFWRnQMTgbHQh2QEMqEAh5DuPyS0EeeQs2QAsnBJnkoHAQLQsAAKACUyAAfMgAAx5ACsyAA-MhqjBqsgWtV-t0QMjkOgRsgALS9D4IJCEJZY7Q4j505CTaAQRZMdC6gCe2AghAQhmwRygJ3UUUI6GkeUk6CMDPxGUJUGJ2KZQA))

```js
interface CompactUser {
    id: number
}

interface DetailedUser {
    id: number
    name: string
    sex: string
}

const compactUser: CompactUser = {id: 1}

const detailedUser1: DetailedUser = {
    ...compactUser,
    name: 'nume',
    sex: 'm',
}

// I don't like this; it's more flexible, but error prone
const detailedUser2 = compactUser as DetailedUser

// ups, I set `sex`, but forgot about `name`
detailedUser2.sex = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'f' : 'm'

// not ok - I access `name` and there's no typescript error
console.log(detailedUser2.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a solution which works, `detailedUser1` in the code below

The way you're doing it is the way you do it, with spread notation as in your example:

```
const detailedUser1: DetailedUser = {
    ...compactUser,
    name: 'nume',
    sex: 'm',
};
```

...or `Object.assign`:

```
const detailedUser1: DetailedUser = Object.assign(
    {},
    compactUser,
    {
        name: 'nume',
        sex: 'm',
    }
};
```

Of those, I'd say spread is clearest and most common. Note that both of those keep **all** properties of `compactUser`, but in your scenario `compactUser` only has properties appropriate to `DetailedUser` so that's fine.

If there are more complicated scenarios, you probably want to put them in a reusable function, but they'll be fundamentally similar.

> I'd like something more flexible (along the lines of `detailedUser2`)...

Your `detailsUser2` doesn't do anything at all to make the object fit the type, it just asserts to TypeScript that it is of the required type. From that point forward, the object is out of sync with its type information, because it doesn't have `name` and `sex` but its type says it does:

```
console.log("sex" in detailedUser2); // false, but the type says it has to be true
```

[Live Copy](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20CompactUser%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20DetailedUser%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sex%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20compactUser%3A%20CompactUser%20%3D%20%7Bid%3A%201%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20detailedUser2%20%3D%20compactUser%20as%20DetailedUser%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22sex%22%20in%20detailedUser2)%3B%20%2F%2F%20false%2C%20but%20the%20type%20says%20it%20has%20to%20be%20true)

That's why you have to do something like what you've done for `detailedUser1`.

If you want to reuse the same object with updated type information, you could do this:

```
const detailedUser2: DetailedUser = Object.assign(compactUser, {name: "x", sex: "f"});
```

E.g., supply the missing properties. That updates `compactUser` in place. (And again, if `compactUser` has properties `DetailedUser` doesn't, they'll be there even though the type says they aren't; but again, that's not the case in your example.)

One of the advantages of both your `detailedUser1` way and the `Object.assign` above is that if you forget a property, TypeScript will tell you:

```
const detailedUser2: DetailedUser = {...compactUser, {name: "x"});
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- Property 'sex' is missing in type 'CompactUser & { name: string; }' but required in type 'DetailedUser'.
```

and

```
const detailedUser2: DetailedUser = Object.assign(compactUser, {name: "x"});
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- Property 'sex' is missing in type 'CompactUser & { name: string; }' but required in type 'DetailedUser'.
```

[Live Copy](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20CompactUser%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20DetailedUser%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sex%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20compactUser%3A%20CompactUser%20%3D%20%7Bid%3A%201%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20detailedUser2%3A%20DetailedUser%20%3D%20Object.assign(compactUser%2C%20%7Bname%3A%20%22x%22%7D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22sex%22%20in%20detailedUser2)%3B%20%2F%2F%20false%2C%20but%20the%20type%20says%20it%20has%20to%20be%20true)

Comment: I see, thanks, maybe it's worth mentioning that `Object.assign` will alter `compactUser` and you won't get errors even if `compactUser` (always) and `detailedUser2` (possibly) receive properties their types don't have (code at https://bit .ly/2WU9Wk7).